API not loading CSV file for Decision Matrix Rows
Using the Salesforce Business Rules Engine, I am able to manually upload a CSV file associated with the Decision Matrix Version to provide the header and rows used for Input and Output values.  I am attempting to do the same using Salesforce's published APIs but am not entirely successful.
Here's what I have done so far:

I created a simple csv file with header and rows matching the Input and Output Data columns that I manually created for the Matrix like so:

Value, Year, Owner, Rate
2500, 2011, Smith, 7.3 
3500, 2020, Davis, 7.1


Uploaded the CSV to confirm that it works manually.
Deleted the existing Rows in the Matrix, leaving the mappings for Input and Output data.

Now to the APIs following this guide...

Captured the record Id values for CalculationMatrix and CalculationMatrixVersion
Received a Bearer token to use with subsequent API calls
Followed the instructions here for preparing the csv as a file for ContentVersion
Encoded the csv as base64 and POSTed to the ContentVersion object, receiving a success response and the Id of the new ContentVersion file.
Assembled the POST following the example below, replacing the Id's as appropriate:

/services/data/v53.0/connect/omnistudio/decision-matrices/0lIR000000000u0MAA
/versions/0lNR000000000rFMAQ/rows
and passing the following body:
{
   "fileId": "used_the_new_ContentVersion_Id_from_above"
}


Received the following response:

{
  "errorFileId": null, 
  "errors": [], 
  "message": "We are uploading and processing the CSV file.", 
  "success": true
}

Although receiving this success=true response, the Matrix rows are not being populated, even after an hour.
I also confirmed that I can use the same values in the POST as above to individually add a row to the Matrix by using the following body:
{
   "rows" : [ {
    "rowData" : {
        "Value": "4200",
        "Year": "2021",
        "Owner": "Mike",
        "Rate": "5.9"
    } 
   } ]
}

I just am unable to see the CSV upload working as expected.

In my experience the API does work, only with bigger CSV files i will take some more time.
